# How to read array values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a response from PHP I am trying to read this on JS but didn't get the value. I want to get the value of **responseCode**. But it returns me undefined.

> Response Code :

```
Array
(
    [request] => 
    [receiptId] => 11233-555
    [responseCode] => 0
    [message] => PSI-3217:Maximum number of attempts reached.
    [transTime] => 4/2/2021 8:50:09 PM
    [merchantEmail] => johndoe@gmail.com
    [merchantId] => 19
)
```

> JS Code :

```
           $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "https://john.com/ca/pay.php",
                data: objData,
                success: function (data, status) {
                    
                    console.log(data['responseCode']);
                   
                },
                error: function (error) {
                }
            })
```

Comment: You should encode the array as JSON and send that JSON to the client.

Comment: I am unable to read the JSON. I am trying by this way JSON.parse(data.responseCode) and return error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 {"request":null,"receiptId":"123555","responseCode":"0","message":"PSI-3217:Maximum number of attempts reached.","transTime":"4\/2\/2021 9:21:38 PM","merchantEmail":"john@gmail.com","merchantId":"10"}
@FelixKling

Comment: If you don't configure jQuery to decode the JSON automatically then you'd have to do `JSON.parse(data).responseCode`. Anyways, the duplicate shows exactly what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use "json_encode" in your php code and return to the request the array in json

Comment: I am unable to read the JSON. I am trying by this way JSON.parse(data.responseCode)  and return error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

{"request":null,"receiptId":"123555","responseCode":"0","message":"PSI-3217:Maximum number of attempts reached.","transTime":"4\/2\/2021 9:21:38 PM","merchantEmail":"john@gmail.com","merchantId":"10"}

Comment: @SaadMasood fix this: console.log(data.responseCode);

Comment: Return undefined  by this console.log(data.responseCode)

Comment: @SaadMasood you must also insert dataType: "json",